# Alternatives to SharePoint 2013 deprecated workflow actions

Tags: designer-workflow

I've just realized that in SP2013 workflows, a lot of actions (and some condition too) have been deprecated and when targeting the new workflow platform (WF4), they are simply not available anymore.

Can someone explain what the alternatives are to each of the following missing actions?
I'm asking only about the ones listed below because I used them in many occasions and I can't really find a good reference on how to accomplish the same result in the SP2013 way.

- Declare Record
- Undeclare Record
- Set Content Approval Status
- Start Approval Process
- Stop Workflow
- (condition) If current item field equals value

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use SharePoint designer then the  best alternative would be to use SharePoint 2010 workflows. SharePoint designer 2013 also allows to create SharePoint 2010 platform workflows which has all these actions. Please see this List of [known issues in SharePoint 2013 designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx#_SharePoint_Designer_1) and the workaround for them.

Comment: holy crap! I can't believe there are so many flaws in SP2013-mode workflows. So, the answer to my question is: keep using SP2010 workflows. Oh, great.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional action "If current item field equals value" is not needed, because it is simply a specific case of the more general "If any value equals any value" condition.

At least for simple workflows, the absence of the "Stop Worflow" action can be worked around simply by including all the workflow action steps you WOULD have placed after the Stop Workflow action within the branch of the condition that is continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a 2010 workflow that has used the list item actions in it. Then the imported workflow in 2013 will have all the list item action ns available to it. To get a sample workflow as a starting point go to this article -> http://techdevforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that SP Workflow 2013 is "not yet available" for those of us with the Office 365 Government E1, Office 365 Government E3, or Office 365 Government E4 plans! Neither apparently is Access Services. But from the question above, apparently we're not missing much on the WF 2013 end...